# How to fix broken display on Samsung Galaxy Tab?

Tags: screen, samsung-galaxy-tab, broken-screen

My Samsung Galaxy Tab felt on the street and the glass on the touch screen is broken. The display still works fine, but it is "danger to touch it", especially for kids.

When I visited repair shop, they asked for the price almost equal to the price of new device.

As it seems to work still fine, my hypothesis is that only the glass is broken, and actually display (electronic device) behind it is ok. And if I would be able to remove the broken glass and get new one (from some ordinary "window maker") and glue it on the display, everything should be ok.

Is that crazy idea or do I have a chance?

Comment: How is it an Android issue?

Comment: @SachinShekhar Strictly speaking it isn't, but neither is the myriad of questions regarding batteries but I haven't seen anyone complaining about those.

Comment: @Richard It doesn't mean this one becomes on-topic. Those questions should be closed too.

Comment: but, only if Android isn't responsible for those battery issues...

Comment: Well, maybe it is not Android issue per se, but "Android Enthusiasts" are the most likely people to give reasonable answer (and indeed answers below are correct ones). The best fit of the question topic and audience, who might know the answer, is something evolving and not necessarily following the definition of "right question". What should we do with these questions, which are not right, but otherwise they are perfect fit for audience?

Comment: There is a video for replacing the screen on the Samsung Galaxy Tab and Galaxy Tab 2 at:
http://youtu.be/fJpNcrpmi_E Its the same process for both and is very easy.

Comment: If the glass is the only thing broken, and not the digitizer, you can replace the glass for probably less than $30. With that said, it requires patients, time, a heat gun, and a careful hand. You have to separate the glass from the digitizer by heating the glue, then slowly pulling it away with a playing card or something firm but thin. Most samsung devices become expensive to replace the screen when the digitizer is broken. Glass ~$20-$30, Glass+Digitizer ~$250. The digitizer includes most of the components to "make the phone", that is why it is so much more expansive.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a new screen through eBay. [Here's one for ~$77](http://cgi.ebay.com/Samsung-Galaxy-Tab-P1000-touch-glass-screen-digitizer-/190537530778?pt=US_Tablet_Accessories&hash=item2c5cebfd9a).

Also, [here's a YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=urGUKerJOhg) that shows how to dismantle and replace the screen and digitizer.

Comment: Ok, it looks interesting (and challenging) :-)
But I will try and let you know how it worked...
Do you know anyone who tried and succeeded?

Answer (score 1):

You can pick up a [replacement](http://cgi.ebay.com/Samsung-Galaxy-Tab-P1000-touch-glass-screen-digitizer-/320705039129) [on eBay](http://shop.ebay.com/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=m570.l2736&_nkw=samsung%20galaxy%20tab%20glass) for ~$80. It looks like they all come with the glass + the digitizer, from what I have read, they are a "combo" item. Then you can find tutorials on how to replace the screen.

Answer (score 1):

If the digitizer still works and the only issue is the sharp edges, I know a bunch of folks that have (device agnostic) cracked screens with a screen protector serving as more of a finger protector on them.